# C code works on Windows (compiled with Visual Studio) but won't compile on Linux (using gcc)

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

I am currently trying to make a very simple C program for school that creates an array of m integer n (both of which are defined by user input) and either returns the location of the starts of the array or an error message if the array could not be created. It works perfectly well when compiled using Visual Studio, but when I tried to compile it using gcc it throws me a heap of error messages and I simply have no idea what is causing them.

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *create_array(int n, int initial_value);

int main(){
    int *arr;
int num;
int numOfNum;

printf("Store this integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &num);

printf("Store the integer this amount of time:\n");
scanf("%d", &numOfNum);

arr = create_array(num, 1);

if(arr == NULL) printf("ERROR");
else printf("Array stored in this location: %p", arr);
    return 0;
}
int *create_array(int n, int initial_value){
int *pointer;
int i;

pointer = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int *p;
    p = pointer;
    p += n*(sizeof(int));
    *p = initial_value;
    }

return pointer;
}
```

Error from gcc:

```
q1.c: In function âmainâ:
q1.c:18: error: missing terminating " character
q1.c:19: error: ânotâ undeclared (first use in this function)
q1.c:19: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
q1.c:19: error: for each function it appears in.)
q1.c:19: error: expected â)â before âbeâ
q1.c:19: error: missing terminating " character
q1.c:20: error: missing terminating " character
q1.c:21: error: missing terminating " character
q1.c:39: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Comment: This is not your problem (I suspect nightcracker has nailed it below), but you should add an `#include <stdlib.h>` to ensure full compaitibility, since that's where malloc is defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeing the weird characters "ânotâ" I suspect that you are using a bad file encoding. Try copy pasting the code into a linux file editor and save it from that editor into a new file. Try compiling that.

Comment: `expected â)â before âbeâ`.  GCC is talking funny too.  Well, as long as he figured it out.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I think that happens because GCC sees weird characters, panics, tries some weird encoding, continues, and outputs error message with that encoding which the terminal doesn't support. Yay me for analytical skills!

Comment: I think you're right, because (for what it's worth) I was able to compile it with zero errors; just one warning about `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, exactly as you posted it, generates these messages with my gcc

```
6398652.c:4:5: error: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
6398652.c: In function ‘main’:
6398652.c:4:5: error: old-style function definition [-Werror=old-style-definition]
6398652.c:18:3: error: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format]
6398652.c: In function ‘create_array’:
6398652.c:25:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
6398652.c:25:21: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

This changed version compiles cleanly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *create_array(int n, int initial_value);

int main(void) {
  int *arr;
  int num;
  int numOfNum;

  printf("Store this integer:\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  printf("Store the integer this amount of time:\n");
  scanf("%d", &numOfNum);

  arr = create_array(num, 1);

  if (arr == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR\n");
  } else {
    printf("Array stored in this location: %p\n", (void*)arr);
  }
  return 0;
}

int *create_array(int n, int initial_value) {
  int *pointer;
  int i;

  pointer = malloc(10 * sizeof *pointer);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int *p;
    p = pointer;
    p += n*(sizeof *p);
    *p = initial_value;
  }

  return pointer;
}
```